# OSX sbrk deprecated

Tags: c, macos, makefile, macos-sierra

I'm trying to build a large binutils file on my mac (running Sierra), and each time it tries to build, it gives me an error saying something along the lines of "sbrk is deprecated". I tried to add a "-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations" flag to CFLAGS in the Makefile, but it wouldn't let me make when I did that, claiming that changes in the environment could compromise the build. Is there anything I can do to get around this problem?

Comment: Did you perform a clean build after changing the Makefile?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: after I modified the makefile, I just ran make. I'm using gcc.

Comment: Supposing that your Makefile has a good "clean" target, try `make clean` first, then `make`.  The objective here is to rebuild the whole project from scratch.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the "proper" way to disable warnings-as-errors in binutils/gdb/gcc is to pass `--disable-werror` to the top-level configure.